# samsung range (fe710drs) is tripping the circuit breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, range

My [samsung fe710drs](https://www.ajmadison.com/cgi-bin/ajmadison/FE710DRS.html) electric range is tripping the circuit breaker any time more than two burners are on, or trying to set the oven for more than 350 degrees.

What's going on?

---

Circuit breaker has "40" on each of the two circuits for the double pole. No test button.

What is odd is that the circuit usually doesn't short until a few minutes after oven or range is on.  We cant figure out if the oven is the problem, or the circuit.

Wanted to add, its a 7 year old range and same circuit breaker. Just a new problem.

***any combo of 3 burners does it.  Or two burners and the oven.  Sometimes just the oven itself will flip the breaker, but only after a few minutes of it being on.

Breaker is warm after tripping

[image]
[image]

Comment: Tell us more about the circuit breaker. What are the numbers on the handles? (e.g. "15" or "20").  Is there a "TEST" button?

Comment: What kind of circuit breakers (do they have a test button?).  What size is the breaker it should be a double pole? Is this a new problem or a new stove?

Comment: Yes, does the breaker for this appliance have a TEST button on it, and what's the breaker amp rating (number on the handle)?

Comment: Is the breaker getting warm when it trips?

Comment: Also, what make and model is your breaker box?

Comment: Yes! Getting warm when it trips

Comment: @LizO'Neill -- can you get us photos of the breaker in question + the label on the inside door of the breaker box please?  Also, is it any trio of burners that trips the breaker, or do specific burners need to be involved?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your question to update it with new information and stop posting updates as answers to your question.

Comment: ...that's the main breaker you took a photo of, not the breaker that you indicated was tripping

Comment: The spec plate on our GE 4 burner range states 13.3 kW with 120/240 V. I didn't recheck the installation instructions but IIRC they specify a breaker not less than 40 A. The breaker is a 50 A because that was there originally to supply the builder installed integrated unit of 4 burner stove, double oven, exhaust fan. The current range has a single oven and the exhaust fan is on a separate circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The 40A breaker is almost definitely the correct size.

The installation manual does not state breaker size but it refers to plug-in installation using ideally a 40A cord but 50A is OK. Plus 2 burners should not be anywhere near 40A. Which means either something is malfunctioning in the range or the breaker is failing.

If you can get an in-use current - clamp meter around one of the hots going to the breaker or to the receptacle then you can see whether it is overcurrent (>40A) or not. If it is overcurrent, range problem. If it is not overcurrent (load <= 40A, except possibly momentary small overage) and the breaker trips then the breaker is failing and tripping at low current (which is better than failing in the other direction, so don't complain).

Replacement breaker should be ~ $10 - $20, depending on manufacturer. **Make sure you get the correct breaker for your panel.** Standard breaker - no need to upgrade to GFCI or AFCI for a straight replacement (new install depends on locally adopted code).

If you don't have a clamp meter, you may want to just get a new breaker and try it.